# STM32 CAN bus silent mode

Tags: stm32, can, bus

I need to use the CAN bus simply to receive frame data (i.e. not transmit.)

Can I use it in silent mode?

I know that the main limitation of this mode is the fact that it does not transmit, so no problem for me.

Should I pay attention to anything in particular?

Can I use this mode for this type of application?

Comment: To add to your main limitation: it doesn’t just not-transmit messages, it also doesn’t acknowledge messages on the bus. If there is no other device acknowledging messages on the bus the sender will repeat its messages or report a failure to its stack. What does you bus look like? How many peers?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I forgot to think about the ACK which allows you to see if the message has been received correctly ... a necessary condition for my application